# Magento cron invalid callback

Tags: configuration, cron

I keep on getting an invalid callback error for my homemade Magento module. I'm using Magento 1.9.2.1 on an Ubuntu web server. My module is stored in: app/code/community/Foggyline/HappyHour/. The specific script is stored in: app/code/community/FoggyLine/HappyHour/Model/Observer.php

Config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foggyline_HappyHour>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </Foggyline_HappyHour>
    </modules>

     <frontend>
         <routers>
            <foggyline_happyhour>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Foggyline_HappyHour</module>
                    <frontName>happyhour</frontName>
                </args>
            </foggyline_happyhour>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <crontab>
      <jobs>
        <happyhour_refresh_cache>
          <schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
          <run><model>happyHour/observer::refreshCache</model></run>
        </happyhour_refresh_cache>
      </jobs>
    </crontab>

</config>
```

Model/Oberserver.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * Checks for invalidated caches and refreshes them
 */
class Foggyline_HappyHour_Model_Observer {
    public static function refresh() {
      try {
        $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();
        foreach($allTypes as $type => $blah) {
          Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
        }
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        // do something
        error_log($e->getMessage());
      }
    }}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a module tag to tell magento where to find the observer

```
 ...
 <models>
     <happyHour>
            <class>Foggyline_HappyHour_Model</class>
     </happyHour>
 <models>
 ...
```

or change

```
 <run><model>happyHour/observer::refreshCache</model></run>
```

To

```
 <run><model>Foggyline_HappyHour_Model_Observer::refreshCache</model></run>
```